# exporting env variables in linux doesn't work with variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am trying to export the value of $fullPath to an env variable with the key WALLPAPER_PATH. But when I execute the following script, the var is empty

**/home/joco/.wallpapers/setwallpaper**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
wallpapers=/home/joco/.wallpapers/pictures/
folder=$(ls $wallpapers | shuf -n1)
file=$(ls $wallpapers$folder | shuf -n1)
fullPath=file://$wallpapers$folder/$file
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri $fullPath
export WALLPAPER_PATH=$fullPath
```

**Shell**

```
╭─joco@Nantaror ~/.wallpapers ‹master*› 
╰─$ ./setwallpaper

╭─joco@Nantaror ~/.wallpapers ‹master*› 
╰─$ echo $WALLPAPER_PATH

╭─joco@Nantaror ~/.wallpapers ‹master*› 
╰─$
```

as you can see it's empty.

Comment: Don't _execute_ the script.  _Source_ it, like `.   ~/.wallpapers`.  When a shell script is executed, it is run as a child process and children can never affect the environment of their parents.

Comment: You should double quote all references to variabes: `folder="$(ls "$wallpapers" | shuf -n1)"` etc.

Comment: tl;dr but I think you want a slash between `"$wallpapers/$folder"`.

Comment: @Roadowl the paths are correct, the slash is set in the second line last char

Comment: @John1024 Thank you very much, that did it. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @Jocomol Glad it worked.  Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't execute the script. Source it, like `. ~/.wallpapers/setwallpaper`.

When a shell script is executed, it is run as a child process and children can never affect the environment of their parents.

In `bash`, as an alternative to the dot-notation above, it is possible to source a script with a `source` command, like `source ~/.wallpapers/setwallpaper`.  This form, however, is non-standard (non-POSIX) and will not work under some very common shells like `dash` (which is the default `/bin/sh` on debian and ubuntu-like systems).

*Additional note*:  Unless you explicitly want *word-splitting* and *pathname expansion*, shell variables should always be inside double-quotes.